# Ahlfors Chapter 4 integral problem

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we  calculate the integral : integral $$ \int\frac{|dz|}{|z-a|^2}$$ along the curve |z|=ρ and |a| is different from  ρ?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Use $z\bar z = \rho^2$ and, writing $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$, note that $|dz| = \left|\rho ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta\right| = \rho d\theta = \rho\dfrac{dz}{iz}$.

Then write $|z-a|^2 = (z-a)(\bar z-\bar a)$ and substitute $\bar z = \rho^2/z$.

Comment: ok  i  know  it  is  given  but  how  make  relation  with |z-a|^2 ??

Comment: I figured you'd see that yourself, but I've added a line.